# Pointwise convergence almost everywhere implies convergence in $L^1$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces, pointwise-convergence

Let $(X, \mathcal{E}, \mu)$ be a measure space and $f_k,f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ integrable functions s.t $f_k \to f$ pointwise almost everywhere. Further, let $g := \sup_k |f_k|$ be integrable. Show that $f_k \to f$ in $L^1(X, \mu)$.

I started like this: By the dominated convergence theorem we have
$$\int f_k \;\mathrm{d}\mu \to \int f \;\mathrm{d}\mu.$$
Since $h_k := |f_k| + |f| - |f_k - f| \geq 0$ we can use Fatou's lemma and it follows
$$\int \lim\inf h_k\;\mathrm{d}\mu \leq \lim\inf \int h_k\;\mathrm{d}\mu$$
which gives us $2\int |f|\;\mathrm{d}\mu \leq \lim\inf \int h_k\;\mathrm{d}\mu$. This is the part where I'm stuck. How should I proceed from here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|f_k| \leq g$ for all $k$ so $|f| \leq g$ almost everywhere. Hence $|f_k-f| \leq 2g$ and $2g$ is integrable. Hence $\int |f_k-f| \to 0$ by DCT.